# Conflict with OpenGL ES rendering and windows multithreading

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, opengl-es

I want to do work preparing my VBO on seperate threads typically 5 or 7. I am not making any OpenGL ES calls on these threads, just getting data into my CPU side vertex buffer which i use to write SubBuffer Data to the GPU side VBO once all the data is ready. I've yet to try to implement this, because just calling _beginthreadex() in benign ways is causing problems with rendering.

Working on this project in Visual Studio, I'm using _beginthreadex() to create these threads, /MT is set, and I've tried calling it from a bunch of locations with and witout arguments, and tried testing it with the thread blocking until completes(just to test with simple functions that take no time) but It's causing some kind of conflict with the the OpenGL side of my code.

Rendering looks like it's at a 1 second framerate, but my actual framerate stays put at 2-3ms, I have timers visable.

Is the context getting screwed up in some way if i open a thread in the middle of the program? I can't figure out why this is happening, and would like any input. I'm using PowerVR's OpenGL ES libraries, do these emulator libraries have a problem with windows multithreading? I'm working on this project in Android Studio as well, tested out pthreads, and no apparent problems there rendering was smooth.

Comment: One possibility is that the PVR emulator has been statically linked with a single threaded C library so you're getting library conflicts. No idea if this is the case though.

Comment: @solidpixel I think you're right. I'm too far along in this project attempt test with other libraries. This project is for Andoid anyhow, so it'd be to far of a right turn to try.